# How to avoid / escape in JSONObject

Tags: android, string, json

Hi I have small problem in escape sequence of JSONObject.

```
JSONObject imageObject = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray imageArray = new JSONArray();
        String imageId = "1/1";
        if (isPOD) {
            try {
                imageObject.put("docidx", imageId);
                imageObject.put("docapp", "LKM");
                imageObject.put("docentity", "DOS");
                imageObject.put("doctype", "PIC");
                imageObject.put("docname", imageTitle);
                imageObject.put("docsize", "" + imageSize);
                imageObject.put("docext", "jpg");
                imageObject.put("docdata64", "");
                imageObject.put("doctxt", documentText);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            imageArray.put(imageObject);
        }
```

The output of this is as follows:

```
12-11 17:49:31.437: I/Parameter(29959): [{"docdata64":"","docentity":"DOS","docsize":"3709","docapp":"LKM","docext":"jpg","doctxt":"fhuuhf","docname":"LKM-PIC_2014-12-11_17:49:31_1\/3","doctype":"PIC","docidx":"1\/1"}]
```

I convert this JSONArray to string and pass it as parameter to POST Method using

```
listLocal.add(22, new BasicNameValuePair("document", "" + imageArray));
```

When this is added to total request and sent to the WS, I get extra escape sequence need help on how to handle the escape sequence.

```
12-11 17:49:32.238: E/param(29959): {"root":{"os":"4.4.2","res":"1280x800","evttime":"17:49:31","gpslon":"79.7898222","dev":"samsung-SM-T231","evtnat":"A","nbcall":"5","ver":"2.0","net":"WIFI","evtctname":"vhhhff","lang":"EN","evtdate":"20141211","ttp":"1418300372","document":"[{\"docdata64\":\"\",\"docentity\":\"DOS\",\"docsize\":\"3709\",\"docapp\":\"LKM\",\"docext\":\"jpg\",\"doctxt\":\"fhuuhf\",\"docname\":\"LKM-PIC_2014-12-11_17:49:31_1\\\/3\",\"doctype\":\"PIC\",\"docidx\":\"1\\\/1\"}]","evttxt":"ghhhgg","shp":"80201\/L2\/74","evtctry":"BM","uuid":"77179677924A49A58FD16D2","evtfam":"G","evtcod":"DEL","evtloc":"dfggg","gpslat":"11.9402385"}}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Why would you need to unescape the string? the server will handle it correctly.

Comment: have you use UrlEncodedFormEntity(listLocal) to setEntity

Comment: @HareshChhelana yes.But If you could see the two logs I have printed the docidx has first a '\' as escape sequence of adding a string in a JSONObject and further adding the JSONArray generates a  "\\" for the newly added '\'.

Comment: Try use 'imageArray.replace( "\\\"", "\"")' instead 'imageArray'

Comment: @TapaSave imageArray is a JSONArray there is no option to replace using JSONArray.replace("\\\"", "\"");

Comment: imageArray.toString().replace( "\\\"", "\"")

Comment: I tried but the String is not getting replaced at all.

Comment: You are using [BasicNameValuePair](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair.html) which by definition encodes everything into one string.